# Jenkins multi branch pipeline not automatically building

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Running Jenkins 2.204.1 on Windows. Subversion plugin.
I created a multibranch pipeline, added a source, as well as a list of branches.
Jenkins is detecting master and branches with Jenkins files in them.
The issue is that Jenkins is not detecting when the source files are updated in SVN.
I believe if I update the Jenkins file itself and check it in, Jenkins will automatically rerun, but if source files are updated, I don't see Jenkin's doing anything.

Seems like I can only trigger a rebuild by using "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now".

Am I missing a configuration? I feel like when I was using a Pipeline project, the checkin detection was working.

Comment: i had same issue, and fix with Jenkins admin assistance, some configuration needed on Jenkins and SVN side.

Comment: What did they do to fix the issue?